# MAAS not PXE booting

Tags: networking, maas, pxe

I decided recently to reinstall MAAS since it was no longer communicating with my nodes. Everything went smoothly except the enlistment. Nobody enlists!

I watched one of the servers trying to PXE boot, and it never finds a DHCP server hosting a bootable image. I have verified there are no other DHCP servers on the network.

I used `tcpdump` to verify that the servers trying to PXE boot are indeed sending BOOTP/DHCP requests that can be seen on the interface hooked up to my MAAS controller, so I believe my network configuration is fine, which seems to isolate this issue to MAAS.

I checked the Services section in the web UI, and dhcpd had no checkmark next to it:

[image: No DHCP screenshot]

`sudo service maas-dhcpd status` returns:

```
● maas-dhcpd.service - MAAS instance of ISC DHCP server for IPv4
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/maas-dhcpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Wed 2016-11-16 16:21:23 PST; 11min ago
           ConditionPathExists=/var/lib/maas/dhcpd-interfaces was not met
     Docs: man:dhcpd(8)
```

`ls /var/lib/maas/` returns:

```
boot-resources  dhcp  dhcpd.sock  gnupg  maas_id  maas-proxy.conf  secret
```

There's no `dhcpd-interfaces` which evidently `maas-dhcpd` was expecting.

How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is missing from the documentation, but if you don't have your own DHCP server somewhere else, MAAS does not automatically enable its DHCP server or give an obvious switch for turning it on. It's somewhat buried within the VLANS page. To fix this, in the web UI:

1. Click the Network tab
2. Click the VLAN you want to run your DHCP server on
3. Click "Take Action"
4. Enable DHCP

This is not an option if you go to the subnet page, so it's really easy to miss this.

Comment: MAAS 1.9 was a little more friendly in my opinion, 2.0 seems a bit more involved, unless you use the CLI which I think 2.0 is easier.

Comment: Except that most of the CLI documentation available is for the 1.9 API, not the 2.0 API.

Comment: MAAS 3,1 and this option doesn't even exist.

Comment: @KenSharp it's now documented here: https://maas.io/docs/snap/3.1/ui/how-to-manage-dhcp